Is it possible to implement nested Enums in Rust, with compile-time checking of variants
In my game, which I am implementing in Rust, I will have an called Condition, which can represent different conditions the character can have.
Within that condition, I want to have a sub-property which defines the stage of the condition (e.g., for pregnancy, trimester 1, 2,3; for cancer, stage I, II, III, IVa,b,c...).
The challenge is to tie at compile time the condition to the condition stage.
Performance is critical (I am simulating a world with 30,000-50,000 characters), therefore I don't want to do runtime checks.
Is there an elegant way to do this, for example are there nested Enums where one value determines the other one?
I am looking to implement something like (as specified in pseudocode):
enum Condition { 
    Cancer(Stage1 | Stage2 | Stage3 | Stage4),
    Pregnancy(Trimester1 | Trimester2 | Trimester3),
    ...
}

The way I am planning to do it is to have two properties, e.g.,
struct ConditionRec {
    condition: Condition,
    stage: ConditionStage,
}


However the problem with that is that the ConditionStage depends on the Condition, and there can be many conditions, and with this approach, there can be a mismatch that the compiler can't check, e.g., ConditionStage::IVa for Condition::Pregnancy.
On the other hand, I don't want to represent the stage as simply u8, since then you can have 45th trimester for pregnancy, and the compiler will not check it again.
Another option would be to define a separate Enum to represent the stage for each condition, such as:
enum PregnancyStage {
    FirstTrimester,
    SecondTrimester,
    ThirdTrimester,
}

enum CancerStage {
    StageI,
    StageII,
    StageIII,
    StageIVa,
    StageIVb,
    StageIVc,
}

enum Condition { 
    Cancer(CancerStage),
    Pregnancy(PregnancyStage),
    ...

But since there will be many conditions (maybe 50-100), I don't want to pollute the code with that many enums.

Having separate enums is probably the "correct" approach here.  If it's not ergonomic, perhaps macros can help?

In fact, I think I remember seeing a crate that enabled you to define your "sub" enums inline with the outer enum definition, though I can't now remember its name.  Have a hunt on crates.io.

I think the basic design is unsound. It is sadly possible to be in the second trimester of pregnancy and have stage 2 cancer...

@eggyal, I was thinking about macros, but I am not good yet at Rust macros. Feels like this is for someone far more advanced with the language. Can you give me some pointers?

@RichardNeumann Actually, I plan to have something like:
struct Character {
    conditions: Vec<Condition>, 
    ...

So this way you can have multiple conditions at once.

That design still does not make sense, since it'll allow vec![Condition::Pregnancy(PregnancyStage::FirstTrimester), Condition::Pregnancy(PregnancyStage::SecondTrimester)].
The struct Character should have something like pregnancy: Option<PregnancyStage>,

@RichardNeumann - you are right here, I however am struggling with the memory footprint, and having an Option 50-100 times, and multiply times 50,000 characters is a lot of memory. I am not using a Vec, but a custom implementation that checks for duplication etc. However this was not relevant to the core question, so I skipped it.

Would probably make more sense to have some sort of conditions set which does not allow two conditions of the same category. Although you could also have a bitmap encoding of your conditions and decode them by hand (this would be more efficient).

Although strict medical modelling is commonly an overfitting e.g. here you're restricting pregnancy duration to 9 months, but 42 weeks (~10 months) pregnancies are common.

@user6029609 you wouldn't need Option - you could just add None as a value in each of the enums

@user6029609 I think you've fallen for the premature optimization fallacy. Even with your numbers above we'd still be in the kilobytes range. If the characters are heap-allocated, this will not be an issue on today's multi-gigabyte machines.

Building off what Richard Neumann said: the order of things to worry about is: being able to write code at all, being able to write correct code, being able to write correct maintainable code, being able to write correct maintainable computational- and memory-efficient code. Unless you are already running into performance issues in your world, it sounds like you might be optimizing too early

Thanks to everyone for the comments :) Indeed this may be too early optimization. Some context: my challenge is that the Character record is already about 20kb and 30,000 characters x 20kb is 600mb; this is the back-end of a web game, so the server should be able to handle multiple games in parallel. I initially started to code this in Python, but no way this will work. I am very very happy that Rust is able to handle such a scale in real-time (e.g. loading a game in miliseconds with bincode, running a game loop in 100-200ms). But this has required constant optimization to stay this way.
